# Correct a carrousel design issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, joomla

I have customised an html-php module to show portfolio images as carousel also i use the same module as in this website

also i have customised the html code of the module but i have a duplication and prev-nav button issue as you look here

can you please help me to fix it ?

thanks
amine

Comment: You need to include the code first and ask a question about the possible issue, not about everything, you can't just wait for an user to give you the answer and do the job for you, this is not the place for that.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation arrow for disable in script So, Please add this

```
navigation: true

EX:
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var owl = $("Your ID/Class");
    owl.owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
});
```

Comment: thans for your help, can you please see my 2 answere i have added the cod with the actual issue ..